# How to declare php echo value in js according to screen size?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to echo php values in js. The idea is to display limited values based on screen size. Here's the code;

```
    <?php
        foreach( $data as $row ){
 $path1 ="
<tr>
<td><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Price (USD)</strong></td>
<td>{$row['name']}</td>
<td>{$row['price']}</td>
</tr> 
";
 $path2 ="
<tr>
<td><strong>Rank</strong></td>
<td><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Price (USD)</strong></td>
<td>{$row['rank']}</td>
<td>{$row['name']}</td>
<td>{$row['price']}</td>
</tr>
";
}?>


<script>
window.onload = function() {
if (screen.width < 960) 

   document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = "<?php echo $path1; ?>";
else

    document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = "<?php echo $path2; ?>";
}
</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <span id ="phone"></span>

    </div>
</body>
```

On running this there is no response (blank) in the window. Why I want to echo the values is because $path1 and $path2 will have values derived from an api, which will generate multiple rows and columns in a table. I am trying to present limited columns of this data when the screen size is small (mobile).

Any help is appreciated.

Rgds.

Comment: 1. This is usually done with css. 2. There's no need to use `<?php echo` inside variable's value.

Comment: `$path1 =
'<tr>
<td><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Price (USD)</strong></td>
</tr>';` and so on for other variable.

Comment: Also don't forget your `<table>` tags

Comment: You better have a look at [mediaqueries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this one with template:

   <?php

$path1 = '';
$path2 = '';
foreach( $data as $row ){
$path1 .=
'<tr>
<td><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Price (USD)</strong></td>
</tr> 
';

$path2 .=
'<tr>
<td><strong>Rank</strong></td>
<td><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Price (USD)</strong></td>
</tr>';

}
?>


<script>
window.onload = function() {
if (screen.width < 960) 

   document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = `<?php echo $path1; ?>`;
else

    document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = `<?php echo $path2; ?>`;
}
</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <span id ="phone"></span>
```

Comment: how to add foreach {} condition to path? It solved problem partly. I've updated the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Works well. Thanks :)